# FSUM7332 - expecting new line when using bpxwunix under z/OS

Tags: mainframe, zos, rexx, omvs

```
sftp 1216: FSUM7332 syntax error: got ), expecting Newline
```

I've created a 'batch' file for sftp in REXX and have used the `address syscall writefile` to write out the data to the file.

the sftp is invoked using bpxwunix thus: sftp -b batchfile userid@host

The file is created thus:

```
stdin = workdir'/'sysvar('sysuid')'.sftp.stdin' 
out.1 = 'put' workdir'/'filename                
out.2 = 'quit'                                  
out.0 = 2                                       
address syscall 'writefile (stdin) 700 out.'
```

I tried to add `'25'x` at the end of each stem line without success.

Comment: which line is failing ?

Comment: I'm invoking sftp via bpxwunix using `sh sftp -b stdin user@host ` and get this.  If I remove the `sh` then the newline error goes away but I get this `FOTS1370 Host key verification failed.:`

Comment: Can you manually connect to that sftp server from a unix shell?

Comment: i changed to use bpxbatch and all is well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can answer why you get an error when running `bpxwunix` with the command passed being `sh sftp ....`:

`bpxwunix` starts a shell as if `sh -c command` has been typed, where `command` is the first parameter to `bpxwunix`. If you pass `sh sftp ...` as the `command`, `bpxwunix` will start a shell as `sh -c sh sftp ...`, so the shell command to be run is `sh`.

If `sh` is called that way, the first word is taken as a shell command file, from which the shell tries to read commands. In your case, the shell tries to read commands from file `sftp`, which is a binary. The error you get is arbitrary, and depends on the bytes read from the file. Try sending `sh ls` as command to `bpxwunix`, and you get some different error.